# String indices before and after transformation

Tags: java, regex, string

In Java I have an arbitrary HTML document as a string. For simplicity, say:

```
String original = "Hello, <strong>this</strong> is a string";
```

And I have a record of various locations in the string, always within the text, not within a tag. For example the index of the start and end of the word "is" are 29 and 31.

I then perform a transformation on the string - in this case stripping out the HTML tags. This leaves:

```
original = "Hello, this is a string";
```

Is there an elegant way of getting the new start and end index of the word "is" now (12 and 14)?

The one possible solution I can think of is inserting a "flag" at each original index, stripping the HTML, then removing the flags while recording their locations. This shouldn't cause any issues with the HTML stripping as the indices always occur outside the tags.

If this is actually the best way, does anyone have any recommendations for a good choice of "flag" that definitely won't coincidentally occur in any HTML documents?

Comment: any reason you can't say: startNew = startOld - (lengthNew - lengthOld) ?

Comment: @mfrankli I think I oversimplified a bit too much for my example - in reality there could be other html tags that occur after desired index that, when removed, would prevent me equating the change in the length of the string with the change in the distance from the start of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is going to depend on how you're stripping the HTML tags. If you're simply removing everything enclosed in <> brackets, then you can just loop through the old string and keep a count of everything outside <> brackets preceding the old index. Something along these lines would probably work:

```
public String newIndex(String str, int oldIndex) {
  int newIndex = 0;
  boolean inBracket = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    if (i == oldIndex) return newIndex;
    char c = str.charAt(i);
    if (c == '<') inBracket = true;
    else if (c == '>') inBracket = false;
    else if (!inBracket) newIndex++;
  }
  return newIndex;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. Ideally I'd like to use something like JSoup to strip the HTML as it includes whitespace normalization and html entity decoding, but this is definitely a possibility.

Comment: As mentioned in the other answer, you'll get better performance if you fold this into the process of removing HTML tags. But doing that by hand is notoriously difficult and you're bound to hit unexpected corner cases. If you have a library at hand to strip out the markup for you and it's feasible to index the output from that instead, I'd definitely recommend that route.

Answer (score 1):

As you strip out each tag, you obviously know the length of the tag you just removed. For each such tag, look for *all* word index values that are *later* than the index of the tag you just removed. For any found, subtract the length of the tag from the indexes. This keeps the indexes in sync as you remove tags, making the task much simpler than trying to calculate adjustments at the end.

Comment: Nice. One drawback is I can no longer use something like JSoup to remove the HTML, I'll have to do it myself via regex. Also, I have a feeling this won't be that efficient, but that's not a massive issue for me.

Comment: How do you initially obtain the word indexes? Can you not simply collect them *after* stripping the tags? You're right, efficiency isn't going to be very good there, but unless you have a huge HTML source or a huge amount of such pages to work on, the difference probably isn't going to hurt the user.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. The main problem is that `String` is final (so you can't extend the class) and that most places where a `String` is used, a `CharSequence` would suffice (where you could in fact create your own implementation).

So you have two choices:

1. Create you own HTML stripping code
2. Reindex the documents again after stripping the HTML tags

If you only need to strip HTML, then you can use this regexp: `<[^>]+>` This is guaranteed to work unless you have [CDATA blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) (which you can check by looking for `<![CDATA[`) or inlined JavaScript (look for `<script>` tags without `src` attributes).

Answer (score 0):

I have created a npm package - **Potsiu!** - to solve this very problem.

Potsiu! finds the index, on the transformed string, for which the surroundings best match the surroundings of the original index in the original string using levenshtein distance.

You can check it out here: [Potsiu!](https://www.npmjs.com/package/potsiu)